# position:absolute and height

Tags: jquery, html, css, height, css-position

I have this example http://jsfiddle.net/HnfCU/ 
I use jQuery to show and hide the `.child` `div`. The `.child` is positioned absolute to `.parent` The problem I try to solve is the height of the `.child`.

I want `.child`'s background to cover it's whole area. Now, using `height:100%` it covers it partially. I can't use fixed height  because the content will be dynamic.

Any method, css or javascript[jQuery], is acceptable, or any change on the structure.

Comment: You definitely need to just make `.child`'s children elements `position: absolute`, as they are not being included when calculating `.child`'s height since they are not positioned absolutely as well. If you just add `.child * { position: absolute }`, it'll include these sub-elements to be surrounded by the backgorund, but you'll have to do some additional styling to get the spacing correct.

Comment: @jerluc thanks for your answer. The sub-elements of `.child` are surrounded because using `position:absolute` they are going on the top left corner of `.child`. But moving them using `top` or `margin-top` or `padding-top` move them out of the background of`.child` also.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, removing `bottom: 5px` and `height: 100%` will get you what you want: http://jsfiddle.net/blineberry/HnfCU/1/

This allows `.child` to get its height from its contents.

Answer (score 1):

Just remove the `bottom: 5px;` style from the `.child` style.

It places the bottom of the child div five pixels above the bottom of the parent div, but as you have placed the top of the child div below the bottom of the parent div this would result in a negative height, so the browser just sets the height to the closest possible value, which is zero.

Also remove the `height: 100%` style, as that only makes the child the same height as the patent, which you don't want as you don't display the child inside the parent.

http://jsfiddle.net/HnfCU/2/